# How to use each line of a file in Perl

Tags: shell, perl

I am working with a remote shell.

I have a file that contains a list of host names, with each host name on a separate line.

For example:

```
FirstHostName
SecondHostName
ThirdHostName
...
```

I want to run through each line of the file and enter the host name by `ssh [hostname]`. Then I'll add some more commands in each loop (after it'll enter).

How should I do this? Assume that I can switch to each hostname.

#### Update

I did some research, and I know it should be something like this:

```
open(FILE, "hostnames.txt") or die("could not open file");

foreach $line ( <FILE> ) {
    ...
}

close(FILE);
```

Comment: Stackoverflow expects you to perform [a degree of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/19068) **before** you ask a question (and to share the results of that research in the question).

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=perl+read+file+line+by+line

Comment: It looks like you have answered your own question?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear...

- If we assume you want to run a specific command on every system :

  ```
  perl -ne 's/^(.*)/ssh \1 some_command/; system $_' < hostnames.txt
  ```
- Or in case you want to do some perl statements after you logged in and out on the remote machine

  ```
  perl -ne 's/^(.*)/ssh \1/; system $_; statement' < hostnames.txt
  ```

Some explanation:

- `perl -ne` runs the argument following it in a `while(<STDIN>) { the_argument; }`-loop. So it will read every line on the input, place it in `$_` and do this until there is no more input.
- `< hostnames.txt` redirects the contents of your file to the `STDIN` (standard input) of the perl process
- `s/^(.*)/ssh \1 some_command/` is a regexp that runs on `$_`. The first part  `^(.*)` means "all characters from the beginning of the line and remember them" and `ssh \1` means "ssh followed by the first thing we remembered".
- `some_command` runs on the remote machine after logging in and exits immediately after it's done.
- `system $_` executes `$_` as if it contains a shell command (which it does now)
- The `;` let's you use multiple statements as a single arg to `perl -ne`